# Counting a field value response weekly basis in Lotus Notes

Tags: view, radio-button, lotus-notes, multiple-columns

I have radio button field in a form whose value can be 1 or 2 or 3. I have a made a view out of this form and there one column will contain the value of this radio button field . Whenever a customer submits the form, a new document will appear in the view. A customer can submit the form many times with different value of this radio button. Is it possible to know how many times a particular customer selected the value 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a view where the first column is your customer name and the second column is their response. Both columns should be "categorized" meaning they'll group the like values.

For each column you can set the formula to include the number of documents within the group. For example:

```
CustomerName + " (" + @DocChildren + ")"
```

will show you "**ABC Company (12)**" if ABC had 12 responses.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If there are 12 documents for ABC company, is it possible to count the value of a field that I mentioned. For example how many times ABC company chose the value 1 and how many times it chose 2 in these 12 documents?

Comment: Yes, apply a similar formula to the second column, which shows the value of the choice field (1,2,3). @DocChildren just shows how many documents are in the group so within the 12 docs for ABC you'll see groupings of each choice with the number of times that choice was made. The key is to make the field categorized, which is essentially saying to group by value.